# Объединить два одинаковых экземпляра класса в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, классы, laravel-9

У меня есть юзеры, допустим два:

```
$user_1 = User::find(1);
$user_2 = User::find(2);
```

Юзеры содержат кошельки, группы итд

```
public function purses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Purse::class);
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Group::class);
}
```

Допустим $user_1 имеет 3 кошелька, а $user_2 имеет 1 кошелек.

Аналогично группы и кошельки содержат категории, доходы, расходы итд

Как мне объединить их в одного $user_family который будет содержать 4 кошелька?

Я пытался сделать через ->push()

```
$user_family = $user_1;
$user_family->purses->push($user_2->purses);
```

В этом случае получаю действительно 4 кошелька, только 4-тый является коллекцией в которой лежит модель

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4882 ▼ // app/Models/User.php:116
    #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => App\Models\Purse {#3955 ▶}
        1 => App\Models\Purse {#3069 ▶}
        2 => App\Models\Purse {#7998 ▶}
        3 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#10909 ▶}
    ]
    #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Этот способ мне не подходит, вызывает дополнительную обработку данных при выводе. Да и у пользователя не только кошельки и группы, порядка 10 разных связей.

Comment: сделали `push` добавили коллекцию целиком. делать, очевидно, надо `merge`. зы: имхо `wallet` более подходит чем `purse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
$user_family->purses->push(...$user_2->purses);
```

Или правильней сделать вот так.

```
$user_family = $user_1->purses->merge($user_2->purses);
```